# select drop down not set the value in ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs

I am using chrome 65 version there the dropdown ng-model works perfectly
but in the chrome 71 version the ng-model malfunctioning it's not set the option value in ng-model .

```
 <select class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-info" ng-model="action" ng-click="disburseMenuEvent(action)">
                                            <option data-icon="fa-glass icon-success" value=""> SELECT </option>
                                            <option data-icon="fa-glass icon-success" ng-repeat="actn in Action"  ng-value="{{actn.Id}}" >
                                            {{actn.action}}</option>
                                        </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace this:

```
...ng-value="{{actn.Id}}" >
```

with this:

```
...ng-value="actn.Id" >
```

Inside an *ng-xxx* attribute, the {{}} markup is not required.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set value for each option. Then it'll apply to the "action" when it is selected.

```
<select name="state" ngModel>
    <option value="" disabled>Choose a state</option>
    <option *ngFor="let state of states" [ngValue]="state">
           {{ state.abbrev }}
    </option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks for you response. but this is angularjs 1.5 version .and your answer is from angular 2 and above..